# Change button background color on toggle

Tags: jquery, button, onclick, toggle

I have a button and i want to change its background color to white on click, and then when i click another time it return back to its original background color, how can i do that?
here is my code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FFF");
                    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is add some sort of toggle boolean, in this example it's the var named 'white'.

```js
var white = false
var bgcolor;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        if (white = !white) {
            bgcolor = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
            $(this).css("background-color", "#FFF");
        } else {
            $(this).css("background-color", bgcolor);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this would be to set the `background-color` using a CSS class, then call `toggleClass()` in the click event handler, something like this:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('foo');
});
```

```css
button { 
  background-color: #000; 
  color: #FFF;
}
button.foo { 
  background-color: #FFF; 
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("new");
  });
});
```

```css
.new {
  background-color: red
}

button {
  background-color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hello</button>
```

1. Use a class with css
2. Use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to switch the class every click

   > Description: Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, simple JS solution;

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   var i=0;
   $("button").click(function () {

      if(i==0){
          $(this).css("background-color", "#FFF");
          i=1;
      }
      else{
          $(this).css("background-color", "#000"); 
          i=0; 
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Record the initial button color, then set/reset based upon state flag

```
$(function(){
  var buttoncolor = $('button').css('background-color');
  var state=true;
  $('button').click(function(){
     if (state )
     {
        $('button').css('background-color','white');
     }
     else
     {
        $('button').css('background-color', buttoncolor );
     }
     state=!state;
  })
});
```